# Output jack came loose on electric guitar, how to reattach/refasten?

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I do not know a lot about guitar maintenance. I have a 7-string electric guitar (Jackson JS22-7). Ever since I bought it I noticed when plugging it in that the output jack wobbles a bit. I picked it up the other day to go to a lesson and saw that there was no jack, just an empty hole. I took off the screws on the back to see if I could quickly figure out how to get it to stay there but could not.

I have taken several pictures of the situation and attached them. If anybody knows how I can secure the jack in place so I can continue playing this guitar I would appreciate it very much! Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It you were my student, I'd expect you to contact me! Looks like you've lost the nut, which needs to be re-screwed onto the rest of the jack socket.

Comment: A slightly unusual thought, but worth getting *two* nuts, and tightening them together, so it never happens again. This is too common an ocurrence.

Comment: I've never had a socket come loose twice. Tighten it properly, it'll never happen again. Bit of superglue on the thread might help too, if you struggle to reach in properly - needle nose pliers don't like being twisted that way ;)

Comment: not super glue, you need to replace the jack sometimes. . Loc-tite or other brand thread lock works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really hard to tell from those photos, but is this bit threaded?

[image]

If so, you've lost the nut that goes on the outside. Any guitar shop should be able to find you one.

After comments: I've never had a socket come loose twice. Tighten it properly, it'll never happen again. Bit of superglue on the thread might help too, if you struggle to reach in properly - needle nose pliers don't like being twisted that way ;)
… or get the guitar shop to do it, if they've got a socket spanner that will fit. It's not a difficult job, by any means, just a bit of a tight space to work in.

Comment: That makes complete sense and I think I can fix that! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've lost the nut on your output jack, so you'll need to find a replacement nut. Talk to the repair tech at your music shop, he has probably got a few extras. You might ask for a matching lock washer and flat washer to go with the nut. Once that has been accomplished you may reassemble by following these steps. First put the lock washer on the Jack, then put the jack into the mounting hole in your guitar. Next comes the tricky part. Take a phillips head screwdriver, put the shaft of the screwdriver through the hole of the nut first, then put the flat washer on the screwdriver shaft. Insert the screwdriver shaft into the hole of the jack and use it as a guide to align the flat washer and then nut onto the threaded sleeve of the jack. Once you have successfully managed to thread the nut onto the jack, remove the screwdriver and use a socket or nut driver to securely tighten the nut. Be careful not to allow the jack to spin while tightening to prevent the breakage of connecting wires on the jack. I wish you best of luck.